# Convert Excel row,column indices to alphanumeric cell reference in python/openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to convert the row and column indices into an Excel alphanumeric cell reference like 'A1'. I'm using python and openpyxl, and I suspect there's a utility somewhere in that package that does this, but I haven't found anything after some searching.

I wrote the following, which works, but I'd rather use something that's part of the openpyxl package if it's available.

```
def xlref(row,column):
    """
    xlref - Simple conversion of row, column to an excel string format

    >>> xlref(0,0)
    'A1'
    >>> xlref(0,26)
    'AA1'
    """
    def columns(column):
        from string import uppercase
        if column > 26**3:
            raise Exception("xlref only supports columns < 26^3")
        c2chars = [''] + list(uppercase)
        c2,c1 = divmod(column,26)
        c3,c2 = divmod(c2,26)
        return "%s%s%s" % (c2chars[c3],c2chars[c2],uppercase[c1])
    return "%s%d" % (columns(column),row+1)
```

Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.utils.html#openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter) does the same function as my columns function above, and is no doubt a little more hardened than mine is. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Yes, and, as it uses a cache, it is a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that during my initial searches, since I was looking for something to translate both the row and column to the string, forgetting that the row part was trivial. Stupid on my part.

Comment: In general, you're unlikely to need to use it.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the full new `xlref` using [`openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter) from @Rick's answer:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def xlref(row, column, zero_indexed=True):
    if zero_indexed:
        row += 1
        column += 1
    return get_column_letter(column) + str(row)
```

Now

```
>>> xlref(0, 0)
'A1'
>>> xlref(100, 100)
'CW101'
```

Answer (score 3):

Older question, but maybe helpful: when using [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter), one can use `xl_rowcol_to_cell()` like this:

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, 2)  # C2
```

See [Working with Cell Notation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html).