# How to write R1C1 reference (a relative address) in excel with python, like (With python)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

in VBA, I can add a formula with an address relative to "current cell". For example, if I write (in VBA code):

```
cells(2,2).formulaR1C1 = "=RC[4]"
```

Then the formula in cell B2 will be "=F2", because column B + 4 (columns), will be column F.

In OpenPyXL, I can't use the =RC[x] style. What are my alternative ways to write a relative REFERENCE (cell's address) in a worksheet cell?

The long option would be, to calculate the address, and add it. e.g.

```
col = 2
row = 2
letter = column_letter(col + 4)
address = letter + str(row)
cell(x,y) = "=" + address
```

1. is there another python writer module, which supports R1C1 notation? i'm trying to google it, but it's not a common topic.
2. In OpenPyXL, is there a shorter way to add relative references?

(I have hundreds of such references inside formulas.)

Comment: What if you set `refMode` to `'R1C1'` when opening a workbook?

Comment: @JohnColeman, in certain circumstances it's much easier to write =RC[-5], than to calculate the row & col, convert to a letter, and write the "normal" address.

Comment: Solution is here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420817/convert-excel-row-column-indices-to-alphanumeric-cell-reference-in-python-openpy

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl itself doesn't really care about what you put in the formulae so you might just be able to use what you have. Otherwise start by examining the source of the worksheet you have. Also cell's have an offset method that will get openpyxl to do the lookup for you:

`ref = cell.offset(row=2, column=-5).coordinate`

Comment: It does care. try to write value like: "=RC[3]", save, and open in Excel. 
 it's probably a bug. Anyway "=R[y]C[x]" is a special construct, which Excel converts on-the-fly to an address.

Comment: I filed a bug report just now, but I doubt it'll be fixed, since R1C1 is not supported, and this is a derivative

Comment: I guess I must work around that (and your suggestion is a good OK workaround, thanks).

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_column_letter function of openpyxl.utils library to transform RC style column number to the column letter of related cell. (the name of the function is also quite self-explanatory)

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

def xlref(row, column):
    return get_column_letter(column) + str(row)

xlref(1, 1)
```

Comment: Kindly add enough details in your answer so that it is clear to the readers.

Comment: I thought that it was self explanatory but I added as you stated.